# Make shell functions only be found in the scope of the importing file

Tags: bash, shell, scope

I declare functions in one shell file,

```sh
# a.sh
foo() { ... }
function bar() { ... }
```

and imported in another shell file by `source`:

```sh
# b.sh
source ./a.sh

# invoke foo and bar
foo
bar
```

Now in the shell, I can use `foo`/`bar` after executing `b.sh`

```sh
$ source b.sh
...

# I can call foo or bar now in the shell (undesirable)
$ foo
...
```

How can I make the functions be local variables in the scope of the importing file, and avoid them to contaminate global/environmental variables?

Comment: `bash` doesn't have modules or namespaces. `source` essentially implements file-level macro expansion. The line `source foo` behaves exactly the same as if you replaced that line with the contents of `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as "file scope" in shell -- just global scope and function scope.  The closest you can come is running b.sh in another shell:

```
$ b.sh   # run b.sh rather than reading it into the current shell
```

then everything in in b.sh will just be in that other shell and will "go away" when it exits.  But that applies to *everything* defined in b.sh -- all functions, aliases, environment and other variables.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to isolates *private* shell functions this way.

```sh
# sourced a.sh

# a_main is exposed public
my_public_a() (
  private_a() {
    echo "I am private_a only visible to my_public_a"
  }

  private_b() {
    echo "I am get_b only visible to my_public_a"
  }

  case "$1" in
    a) private_a;;
    b) private_b;;
    *) exit;;
  esac
)
```

```sh
# b.sh
source a.sh

my_public_a a
my_public_a b
private_a # command not found
private_b # command not found
```

Comment: @李岡諭 Caveats: the container sub-shell is a new instance at each invocation and so cannot persist variables between calls. It is also re-instantiating its inner function declarations each time. Some prefer to simulate library namespace with declaring functions as `lib_name::function_name` See my https://github.com/leagris/lcnumconv.sh as a bash library sample

Answer (score 0):

Even though bash does not provide direct support, what you need is still achievable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# b.sh

if  [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "$0" ]] ;then
    source ./a.sh

    # invoke foo and bar
    foo
    bar
else
    echo "b.sh is being sourced. foo/bar will not be available."
fi
```

Above is not 100% reliable, but should cover most cases.